# finding direction and angle of swipe in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swipe, angle, direction

I've just started work on a new game in which the player will fire a projectile by swiping in the direction he needs it to go in.  I know how to detect if a swipe is left, right, up, or down using gesture recognizer, but I need to know how to get the angle of the swipe so the projectile can be fired in whatever direction and at whatever angle the player desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead. Unlike the swipe recognizer, it's called continuously but with different states, so you could do something as simple as just handling the start and end states.

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html